# Beresheit 3:21: What was the material Hashem used to cover Adam and Chava?

Tags: clothing, parashat-bereishit, adam, gan-eden, eve-chava

I'm seeking a general consensus on what material Hashem used to clothe Adam and Chava. I realize there are various translations stating they were leather or animal skins. Commentaries range from materials like that of fingernails or wool or linen. The Hebrew word used is kotnot but that means gown or garment but does not describe the actual material it was made of.

Comment: To rephrase @AlBerko’s comment: It’s Judaism. You can have two answers that say completely opposite things and are both correct.

Comment: The word after כתנות in that sentence is עור. Is there some reason to believe עור does not describe the material used? Are you looking for something other than the standard translation of that word?

Comment: @DonielF I like your comment, can you provide a rabbinic reference please.

Comment: @ninamag If I provide a Rabbinic reference, would I have to cite one that argues on it? :) The principle is commonly referred to as אלו ואלו דברי אלקים חיים הם - “these and these are the words of the living G-d.” See, for instance, Eruvin 13b.

Comment: @Ephraim77  "fingernails or wool or linen" - please provide a link to each of these.

Comment: Very disappointing response - at https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en I found various answers - and at this rate I may just answer this myself.

Comment: @DannySchoemann you commented, "at this rate I may just answer this myself." ok and your take on this is?

Comment: @ninamag - to simply review the sources that I wrote for you at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95843/501 and upload the views on the material (as opposed to the description that I did for you.)

Comment: @ninamag. I don't have links per se but this is from Chabad.org's Parsha in-depth section: 
Isaac the Elder said: They were as smooth as a fingernail and as beautiful as a jewel.
Rabbi Yosei bar Rabbi Chanina said: It was a garment made of skin with its wool.
Resh Lakish said: It was of Circassian wool, and these were used [later] by the firstborn.
Rabbi Samuel ben Nachman said: They were made from the wool of camels and the wool of hares, “garments of skin” meaning those which are produced from the skin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Midrash Rabbah - [Genesis XX:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.20.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Skin was a smooth and shiny surface that was fingernail-like. Machlokes in the [Gemara Sotah (14a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.14a.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) if they were clothed in a type of animal's hide and which type of animal.

Comment: Where's the machlokes in the Gemara?

Comment: This is a good start, but no more than that.

Comment: @ezra Sotah 14a - https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.14a.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en

Answer (score 1):

The original body was light (אור) or as the Ari calls it "electromagnetic radiation" (גוף החשמל). (For the association of אור, נורא, חשמל and אש, see [Chagigah 13a at the end and 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.13a.11-13b.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) After the sin, it was completely covered in skin (עור).

[This is discussed by the Ari z"l in Eitz Chaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Etz_Chaim.49.5.1?vhe=Sefer_Etz_Chaim&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). The Ari explains that this secondary body is referred to as "גוף הצואה", the 'Fecal body'. It essentially ties us to the process of decomposition/decay and defecation.

That is why, for example, after receiving the Torah initially, there was no longer defecation. The body was returned to it's original perfected state and the food (*Mannah*) was also in a perfected state of existence.

This also follows the explanation from Sefer [Shnei Luchot HaBrit](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Asara_Maamarot%2C_Second_Maamar.44?vhe=Shenei_Luchot_HaBrit,_based_on_Amsterdam,_1698_ed._Part_I&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> והענין כאלו תאמר **הנשמה בגוף אור**, ו**הגוף אור בגוף עור כבלע את הקודש בנרתק שלו**, אבל לא נתבטל כתנות אור, רק נבלע בנרתק **וזה אור הגוף הזך והדק הוא לישראל דוקא ונמשך להם מאדם הראשון**, על כן אתם קרוין אדם (יבמות סא, א). **ובעת מתן תורה שפסקה זוהמת הנחש (שבת קמו, א) היו הנשמות מלובשים כמו בכתנות** **אור**, **רצה לומר שהיו עומדים בלבוש זך ודק** כעצם השמים לטוהר שהוא הכח של כתנות אור, נמצא היו בגוף ונפש. וכן בערבות מואב אף שהיו מלובשים בכתנות עור, מכל מקום התעורר בהם הגוף הזך והדק כי נתקדשו והיו עדה שלמה כמו שכתוב (דברים ד, ד) ואתם הדבקים בה' אלהים חיים כולכם היום, וזה הגוף הזך והדק מתפשט בכל דור ודור כל מי שרוצה לעורר אותו:

The *Garments of Skin* (כתנות עור) are what you see as skin on your own physical body even today.

And this is part of why some teachings in Torah say there will be no substantial change between *Olam HaZeh* and *Olam HaBa*. Because these seemingly miraculous conditions associated with the World to Come are how the Creation was before the sin of the Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil.

Comment: please provide a link discussing "after receiving the Torah initially, there was no longer defecation."

Comment: Although חשמל means "electricity" in Modern Hebrew, that's not a good translation for the word in a Biblical or Rabbinic sense.

Comment: @ezra You may have greater expertise in this area than the Lubavitcher Rebbe. But he said it is to be understood as electricity and that electricity is a type of fire based upon Yechezkel 1:27. Last time I checked, Yechezkel wasn't known for his Modern Hebrew. Interestingly enough, אור, אש וחשמל are all related. They shine, glitter and glow. They also burn/oxidize. Oxidation is releasing oxygen from the other elements it is bound with. From a Torah context, that is releasing Ruach from its being bound to Afar (Dust/Earth).

Comment: The 4 elements mentioned by Rambam in Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah are:  (אֵשׁ) Fire/Light/Electricity, (רוּחַ) Wind/Soul/Breath, (מים) Water and (עָפָר) Dust/Earth.

Comment: @YaacovDeane L'havdil me and the Rebbe

Comment: @ezra Shavuah Tov. I looked at this subject over Shabbat. You should look at Chagigah 13b. It discusses the whole subject and connects ‘chashmal’ with electricity, fire and light together with the concept of ‘Ratzu v’Shuv’.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks for looking into it more. Shavua Tov

Answer (score 0):

**[*Leather garments:*](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=1&CHAPTER=3#C37)**

> Some translate this 'shrouds of skin,' denoting the growth of the male foreskin and female hymen (Maaseh HaShem; from Sanhedrin 38b, Eruvin 100b).