# What was the size of the כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, parashat-bereishit, parts-of-the-body, men-male

What was the size of the כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר (garments of skins for Adam and his wife) ([Genesis 3:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))?

By "size", I mean, was the garment just covering the area that an underwear would cover, or was it a shoulder-to-feet covering, etc.?

Please provide a rabbinic source for an answer.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95276/16706

Comment: @Shmuel thanks for that, the difference is that it did not ask for the "size", which I did.

Comment: @Al_Berko, there was a reason that I did not spell out a possible translation for    "כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר" is because I did not want to influence the answer to the linked question, which is "What was the material Hashem used to cover Adam and Chava".  There is/are rabbinic opinion/s that suggest this was not a garment, but made of "nails" etc.

Answer (score 6):

The [Bartenura on that verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Bartenura_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.3.21.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) says that the כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר covered their entire body - I guess like a long robe.

He explains that this is the reason the *fig leaves* needed to be replaced, because they only covered *the area that an underwear would cover*, as you so politely worded it.

Now they were properly attired with their כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר.

> **כתנות עור** חלקים כצפורן פי' רש"י כן לאפוקי ממאן דאמר עור מלא שער. איתא במדרש שזהו עור זוגו של לויתן שמלח הקב"ה לצדיקים לעתיד לבא. וקשה אמאי אצטריכו להני כתנות הא כתיב לעיל ויעשו להם חגורות? י"ל שאותן חגורות לא היו מכסות אלא ערותן בלבד **ועכשיו בא והלביש את כל גופן באלו הכתנות עור**:‏

The [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Chizkuni%2C_Genesis.3.21.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) similarly says that the fig leaves only covered them from their waist down, and the כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר covered their entire bodies.

> **וילבשם**. בתחלה ויעשו להם חגורות משמע ממתנים ולמטה ולבסוף כתנות עור וילבשם לכל גופם.‏

Also see [Rabbeinu Bachya](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bereshit.3.21.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) who says that the כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר were respectable and high-class attire as opposed to *the underwear* they fashioned out of fig leaves.

> **ויעש ה' א' לאדם ולאשתו כתנות עור**. ע"ד הפשט עשה להם מלבושים מעולים ונכבדים מעור יתעטפו בהם כל גופם דרך כבוד כי היה כבודם לכלמה אם יעמדו באותן חגורות שעשו להם לכסות בשר ערוה בלבד.‏

The [Rashbam](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashbam_on_Genesis.3.21.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) also says it was a robe that covered their entire body.

> **כתנות עור וילבישם** - כתנות להלביש כל הגוף.‏

Comment: thanks for the answer. Very informative. Of the various sources that you referenced, I am just curious, if each one gave their opinion as to what the robe was made of? Kosher Animal? Or otherwise?

Comment: Is it also ok to refer to כָּתְנ֥וֹת as vestment, shroud, etc...?

Comment: @ninamag, from context, I think tunic would be appropriate, comp. Aharon's כתונת

Comment: @ninamag - that belongs in the linked question - which has  a poor answer. The Bartenura mentions that it was made from the Leviathan skin; the one that was salted for future use. The others don't seem to address that issue... but I wasn't paying attention as I was looking for an answer to your original question. :-)

Comment: I have a few fig trees in my yard. I admit that I haven't actually tried the Adam / Chava experiment, but, judging from the size and especially the shape of fig leaves, I'm surprised that these could do a sufficient job of covering their privates. My understanding is that Gan Eden had many types of trees. Palm fronds would have done a much more thorough job!

Comment: @DanF - Keep in mind that this was The Original Fig Tree - and its leaves may have been bigger and sturdier than the ones we see 5700+ years later.

Comment: OMG! That sounds a bit like the veggies in the movie "Sleeper".

Comment: @DannySchoemann my hereby question is inspired by your comment. Do you know if it has been discussed here at mi yodeya about the size of the sheep or ram, that is, were such much bigger during pre-flood, pre-noah, times, as it is now? I was just thinking if it is possible to have a tunic-size garment or robe-size garment from a sheep or ram, assuming one of our sages have said the כָּתְנוֹת עוֹר material is from a sheep or ram?

Comment: @ninamag - not sure what you're asking - a ram is large enough to make a very large leather coat, even nowadays - but nowhere does it say that it wasn't made from multiple animals. (For that matter it doesn't say it came from an animal; maybe it was Gcdly leather, created on the spur of the moment. IDK.)